# In a view, how can I display all sub categories of a given taxonomy term with content from each sub category?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

For each article, I assign a 'sub-category' taxonomy vocabulary term.  Then for each 'sub-category' taxonomy term, it links to a 'category' taxonomy vocabulary term.

I have set up a variant of the taxonomy-term template page that passes the category ID as an argument to a view.  This view then uses a contextual filter to display all content within all sub-categories for the given category ID.

To illustrate, say you type in sitename.com/taxonomy/term/1922 which is, say, movies.  The view will display all content marked with movies' sub categories.  So it currently would show this:

```
/taxonomy/term/1922 (Movies)  
Title         |      Sub-Category |
——————————————————————————————————-  
Star Wars     |            Sci-Fi |  
Star Trek II  |            Sci-Fi |  
Home Alone    |            Comedy |  
Office Space  |            Comedy |  
Thin Red Line |               War |
```

What I want is to have, say, 5 pieces of content per sub-category titled by the sub-category.  Something like this:

/taxonomy/term/1922 (Movies)

- Scifi:

  1. Star Wars
  2. Star Trek II
  3. ...
  4. ...
  5. ...
- Comedy:

  1. OFfice Space
  2. Home ALone
  3. ...
  4. ...
  5. ...

And so forth.  So that it would title all sub-categories and show the top x number of nodes per sub-category.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a great answer, but after a couple days of trying to do this myself, the best I could figure out was to use [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) (I think that [Views Grouping Row Limit](http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping) would probably work too, but it's still in dev).

Create a basic node view that lists off your five movie node titles (along with any other teaser-like content you'd like), set your page to limit to five entries, and set the contextual filter to the movie's taxonomy term.

Then, make a view that shows taxonomies belonging to the vocabulary (movies). Set the contextual filter to "taxonomy term: parent term"), and output the tid (hidden) and term title. That'll make a list of your parent terms, so now add a views_field_view (set it to use your first view for input, and the tid for your argument).

Again, there's got to be a better way than this, as I'm sure it's going to create some real system overhead.

Pleeeease, someone come up with a better answer!